# Cannot find elements in a aspx site

Tags: java, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm new using Webdriver (java) and I´m trying to automatize a couple of test for an app that only runs on IE. The app is an aspx.

The login of the app can be automated correctly but as soon as the driver enter the home page, none element is recognize.

I print the source code and I receive this: 
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.46.0.0
Listening on port 2119
Negocio.Net

However, when I use the "Developers tool" of IE to identify the elements the code is different.

How can I do to see the "dynamic source code" and not the static one???

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `iframe` element having the full page content inside. You need to switch to that `iframe` first, then locate the desired elements:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Here we are switching to the first (and only) iframe.